# CJuiDatePicker in yii is not working

Tags: yii, datepicker

In my web application, I want to implement a date field. For this i am using CJuiDatePicker. But for me it not showing calendar.

My code is,

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                        'name' => 'Employee[employee_joiningdate]',
                        'id' => 'Employee_employee_joiningdate',
                        'value' => Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("d-M-y", strtotime($model->employee_joiningdate)),
                        'options' => array(`
                            'showAnim' => 'slide', //'slide','fold','slideDown','fadeIn','blind','bounce','clip','drop'
                            'showOtherMonths' => true, // Show Other month in jquery
                            'selectOtherMonths' => true, // Select Other month in jquery
                        ),
                        'htmlOptions' => array(
                            'class' => 'form-control'
                        ),
                    ));`
```

What i am doing wrong?

Please help me....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have jQuery loaded for that page?

Comment: @Yasky No, How to load the jQuery in a page.

Comment: make sure you have a `jquery` spec in `components.clientscript.packages`

Comment: I resolved my problem by using jQuery datepicker. but can't change the date format.                                                                 $(document).on('focus', ".datepicker", function () {
                $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'Y-m-d' }).val();
            });